# Single row subqueries error

Tags: oracle

I have a table on oracle sql called employees. What I'm trying to do is return the department ID and minimum salary of all employees, grouped by 
department ID, having a minimum salary greater than the minimum salary of those 
employees whose department ID is not equal to 50.

This is what I came up with:

```
select department_id, min(salary) 
from employees where min(salary)>(select min(salary) from employees 
where department_id!=50)
group by department_id;
```

Oracle is giving me error: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using an aggregate function for filtering, you need to place that code in a [`HAVING`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/having.php) clause. You cannot use an aggregate function in a `WHERE` clause:

```
select department_id, min(salary) 
from employees
group by department_id
having min(salary)>(select min(salary) 
                     from employees 
                     where department_id!=50)
```

Comment: Shoot, I didn't even think about that! Thanks a bunch!